# Function call using for-loop in flutter

Tags: flutter, for-loop, dart

I have a function written and want to call it using for-loop so that it is dynamic. The following code is for the function:

```
 var cardList = [
    {"img" : "assets/1.png", "icon" :"assets/icon1.png", "name" : "card1"},
    {"img" : "assets/2.png", "icon" :"assets/icon2.png", "name" : "card2"},
    {"img" : "assets/3.png", "icon" :"assets/icon3.png", "name" : "card3"},
    {"img" : "assets/4.png", "icon" :"assets/icon4.png", "name" : "card4"},
  ];
  Widget cards(img, icon, name){
    return Container(
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {},
        child: Card(
          elevation: 5.0,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0)),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Image(image: AssetImage(img)),
              Row(
                children: [
                Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0)),
                Image(image: AssetImage(icon),),
                Container(
                  child: Text(
                    name,
                  ),
                ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          )
        )
      ),
    );
  }
```

Now to call it in the main code, I have:

```
Container(
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  children: [
                    for(var i in cardList)
                    cards(...)//not sure how to call this
                  ],
                  ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Container(
    child: GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: cardList.length,
      children: cardList.map((item) {
        return cards(item["img"],item["icon"], item["name"]);
      }).toList();,
),),
```

Comment: I tried it, but there was an error `Vertical viewport was given unbounded height`. I have given height and width to the very first container next to return, yet not working.

Comment: @yaminir Container set height: double.infinity

Comment: For which Container should I set this height?

Answer (score 1):

The vertical viewport was given unbounded height error because  `shrinkWrap` and `ScrollPhysics` both are missing.

```
Container(
                child: GridView.count(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                  crossAxisCount: cardList.length,
                  children: cardList.map((item) {
                    return cards(item["img"],item["icon"], item["name"]);
                  }).toList();,
                ),)
```